# ¿Como puedo hacer un botón en en canvas?

Tags: canvas, botón

Necesito hacer un botón en el canvas, pero solo se este código y solo quiero usar canvas:

```
Raphael(0,0,0,0).rect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    .attr({fill: "#000"})
    .click(function () {
        alert('second rectangle clicked');
     });
```

en este codigo necesito usar framework de raphael 2.1.0

Comment: Hola Humberto, y qué problema tienes?  Te da algún error? Un saludo

Comment: NO, ESQUE SOLO LO QUIERO HACER EN CANVAS

Comment: si, eso me quedo claro con el título. no uses mayúsculas porque en Internet significa estar gritando... mira [ask] para saber como hacer una buena pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Mira aquí hay un buen **ejemplo** de cómo hacer la interacción sin necesidad de usar un framework, así como usar el **Canvas** o **SVG** si lo prefieres.

Usando SVG solo hace una llamada a la función en Javascript que quieres que haga en el código veras la línea como `onclick="clickMe();"`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
            <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          // La función se llama cuando se hace click en el canvas
           function clickMe() {
//Muestra una alerta
            alert("You clicked the SVG UI element.");

          }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <h1>
          SVG User Interface
        </h1>
        <!-- Create the SVG pane. -->
        <svg height="200" width="200">
          <!-- Create the circle. -->
          <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="gold" id="uIElement" onclick="clickMe();"
          />
        </svg>
        <p>
          Click on the gold circular user interface element.
        </p>
      </body>
        </html>
```

[Creación de elementos de la interfaz de usuario con Canvas o SVG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/gg589494(v=vs.85).aspx)